# Using TinyXML to parse XML file string

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I have a library that contains a default XML file represented as a `const char *` stored byte by byte.

I want the user to be able to request a handle to this file (as a [TiXmlDocument](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlDocument.html)).

Currently, I'm trying to do this by passing this string `defaultFile` (its defined in its own header file) to `TiXmlDocument.Parse()`.  The `Parse()` is passing me back a garbage pointer (but not null) which causes a crash on an attempt to call `SaveFile()`.

I'm able to work around this by writing the same `defaultFile` to a file using:

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen("temp.prme", "w");
fprintf(file, "%s", defaultParameterFile);
fclose(file);
```

I create a new `TiXmlDocument` using the constructor that takes a file path as input.  This works, but it's not a real option because I don't want to be saving files to the users machine.

From what I can tell, all the constructor is doing is reading the string from the file, and then sending it straight to the `Parse()`.  I checked the values that were being passed in memory and found very few differences.

When using the constructor method, you must cal `LoadFile()` afterwards.  In `LoadFile()`, the string being passed to the `Parse()` was NOT null terminated.  Even though `defaultFile` was.  Also, all new lines (which in `defaultFile` were listed as `/r/n`, were listed as `\n\n`.

I tried modifying `defaultFile` to match what I was seeing from the constructor, and had no luck.  Any Suggestions?

For what its worth, `defaultFile` is laid out roughly like this:

```
const char defaultFile[] = {
/* 0x00000000 */   0x3C, 0x3F, 0x78, 0x6D,
...
};
```

It's roughly 9000 lines long, with 16 bytes per line.

Comment: There have been a few bugs there in the past, but I think they are fixed now. Anyway, you really have to NUL-terminate your string before passing it to `Parse()`. And what is that constructor that loads a file?

Comment: @rodrigo My point is that the constructor isn't doing it, so I don't have control over that, and its working without the null.  The documentation for the constructor can be found [here](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlDocument.html#e4508b452d0c3061db085f3db27b8396)

Comment: In this doc it says that it is the name and filename of the document, not that it loads it. You have to call `LoadFile()`. And that it works without the NULL may be just chance, because it happens to be a NUL byte just after the string, but it _may_ not happen.

Comment: Also note that `TiXmlDocument::LoadFile()` normalizes the end-of-lines so that `Parse()` only sees `\n` and never `\r`.

Comment: @rodrigo you're right, I forgot that I was calling that afterwards.  I'll edit to include that.  Still, I looked in memory at what the `LoadFile()` was passing to `Parse()` and found that there was no null termination.  It was just garbage memory, in this case 0xCD.

Comment: In my copy of the source at `TiXmlDocument::LoadFile()`: `assert( q <= (buf+length) ); *q = 0; Parse( buf, 0, encoding );`. See the `0` (`q` points to the middle of `buf`). Then yes, there will be garbage because the buffer has more length than needed, but that will not matter because it will not read past the NUL.

Comment: @rodrigo Thats the point, there is no NUL.

Comment: See the `*q = 0;`? There is the NUL byte! Maybe you would prefer to write `\0`, but it is equivalent!

Comment: Ok, that sort of makes sense.  Regardless, I tried modifying the string to have a null and not have a null, none of it is working

Answer (score 0):

When calling into the `Parse()` directly, I was allocating the `TiXmlDocument` on the stack.  The data was being corrupted by other function calls.  I fixed that and everything worked.